# Proper place for views tests in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I want to test the presence of certain page elements in views and wonder
where such testing belongs - controller unit tests with integrated
views or integration tests.

How do you test views and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration tests, almost always. Make them a part of your end-to-end tests, preferably using cucumber or rspec/capybara.

Also, test for content, not the technicalities of HTML in the views, as the latter will make things brittle and hard to redesign.

Comment: Thanks, Srdjan. I guess unit views testing separated from controller-generated data is kind of pointless, but why not controller tests? Also, let's say I have a resulting grid with two columns and I want to check the presence of a certain row with values A and B. Assuming capybara, what kind of matcher would you use to test that A and B are present, A comes before B. How would you write it so to avoid HTML technicalities (say <table> design that might be replaced with <div> kind of design, etc.)? Would you test for anything else but presence and sequence?

Comment: Controller tests should test the logic in controller actions. Set up the data an action needs to receive and test that it does the right thing with it, as well as how it handles the exceptional cases. They shouldn't test what the view does with the data provided.

Comment: I would first ask why are you presenting tabular data without using a table? That's what it's for. Beyond that, I'd wrap the content in a <span> and test for its presence + the content in it. To test the sequence, try using the next sibling CSS in capybara's matchers.